# How to set the font inside the spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

```
I want to show the custom font In my Application. I want to show the custom font inside the spinner. For that I have used the custom adapter for creating the spinner. 

I am getting the output that I want when spinner opens And I am getting the custom fonts. But when spinner close that time word is not readable font is not setting.

Image1: Inside the spinner the word is not readable.![enter image description here][1]  


Image2: when spinner open the word is readable:
![enter image description here][2]

I have used the 
**Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/kalpurush.ttf");**

**textViewlistview.setTypeface(tf);**

But how should I set the font inside the spinner. when settext inside the spinner.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i02XA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkydk.png
```

Below is the adapter that I am using the spinner

```
private class CustomAdapterSpinner extends ArrayAdapter
    {
        public CustomAdapterSpinner() {
            //super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);
            super(CustomizeFontsAndroid.this, R.layout.simple_spinner1,R.id.textviewSpinner,strarraySpinner);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            tf1=Typeface.createFromAsset(CustomizeFontsAndroid.this.getAssets(), "fonts/kalpurush.ttf");
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textviewSpinner = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewSpinner);
            textviewSpinner.setTypeface(tf1);
            textviewSpinner.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            textviewSpinner.setTextSize(16);
            textviewSpinner.setText(strarraySpinner[position].toString()+"\n");
            //textviewSpinner.setText(R.string.bangla);

            return view;
        }
  }//end of the Spinner Adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using an adapter to create the views for the spinner.  Even if the view the adapter creates is just a `TextView`.  Doing that will let you call `setTypeface()` on the `TextView`.

I read your comment, but you need to do this in the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`.  Make sure your `Adapter` implements `SpinnerAdapter`.  `SpinnerAdapter` has two methods that return views, `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`.

`getView()` returns the view that is used for display purposes, i.e. when the popup for the spinner is not displayed (the one that is not using the right font for you).

`getDropDownView()` returns the view that is used in the list of items for the spinner.

Check out the reference for [SpinnerAdapter here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html).

Comment: @Flunn81 I am using the custom adapter only. Inside that I am using the Textview. and I am using Typeface. I have already mention that in question. as you seen in question there are two screen shot In first Image the look the spinner the font is not getting set but when I open the spinner check the Image 2 I can see the words properly. My question is how to set font when word put inside the spinner.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.  I misunderstood.  Looking into it now.

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution.  Change your adapter to use SpinnerAdapter, if it doesn't already, and use getView() to change the typeface for the view that is causing you problems.  getDropDownView() is used in the list.

Comment: Try adding implements SpinnerAdapter to your adapter. You need both of the methods from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this. In your CustomAdapterSpinner override getView(), that method is where you can change the typeface of the TextView.